Lattice MachXO3LF FPGA Internal Clock Accuracy
On the data sheet for the Lattice MachXO3 FPGA family, it shows that the internal oscillator has varying nominal frequencies with +/- 5% accuracy. Does this apply to its entire temperature range specified in the data sheet? If the FPGA is operating near its max/min temperature, will the internal oscillators accuracy reduce more, and if so, how much?

The datasheet I read specifies fmax in terms of min/typ/max frequency with the temperature range. The percentage value is probably a marketing spec. Nevertheless, you should direct your questions to Lattice support - we’re not the manufacturer.

The MachXO3 Family Data Sheet has the following:

Which shows the overall accuracy depends upon the grade:



Grade
Temperate range
Worse case Oscillator accuracy




Commercial
0 to 85°C
+/- 5.5 %


Industrial
–40 °C to 100 °C
+/- 6.5 %


Automotive
-40 to 125°C
+/- 8 %



Looking at the datasheet I can't find any information on how the internal oscillator frequency changes with temperature. Lattice may not have characterised the information.
If the design needs a more accurate oscillator than the worst case in the published datasheet, an external oscillator with a tighter frequency will be preferable.
